# Blocking certain functions while checking leaks with valgrind

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

In my program I'm using GNU Readline and the functions from that library causes some leaks. While using Valgrind I don't want to see those leaks. Can I somehow block some functions?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting lots of this kind of leak warnings from using `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./program`

```
==2376== 28,784 bytes in 7 blocks are still reachable in loss record 57 of 57
==2376==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2376==    by 0x489500C: xmalloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8.0)
==2376==    by 0x4873A91: rl_make_bare_keymap (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8.0)
==2376==    by 0x487AD79: rl_generic_bind (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8.0)
==2376==    by 0x487CA92: rl_parse_and_bind (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8.0)
==2376==    by 0x487CC6C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8.0)
==2376==    by 0x486F228: rl_initialize (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8.0)
==2376==    by 0x486F4AF: readline (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8.0)
==2376==    by 0x10B6B5: main (main.c:77)
```

I made a file named `supp.supp` and wrote in it:

```
{
    ignore_libreadline_leaks
    Memcheck:Leak
    ...
    obj:*/libreadline.so.*
}
```

After this, I added `--suppressions=supp.supp` flag. All leak errors from libreadline is now suppressed.

Comment: Also you can use `--gen-suppressions=all` to make it easier to produce your own suppressions file.